# Updating nested object properties

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to update the value of a nested object.

Object:

```
var data = {
  "key 1": {
    "jan-16": 0,
    "feb-16": 0,
    "mar-16": 0
  },
  "key 2": {
    "jan-16": 0,
    "feb-16": 0,
    "mar-16": 0
  }
}

data["key 1"]["jan-16"] += 250;
```

The problem is that all I'm doing is adding 0 + 250 but not actually updating the object value

This is how I'm trying to do it with other code:

```
    if(firstBillDate.isBefore(dateEnd)) {
      while(intervalIterator > 0) {
        let targetService = report[service][monthInterval];
        if( !_.isNull(targetService) && !_.isUndefined(targetService) ) {
          targetService += cost; // Nothing is happening here
          monthInterval = moment(monthInterval).add(pmtInterval,'month').format('MMMM-YYYY');
          intervalIterator -= pmtInterval; //12-4
        }
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't the code shown give an error in the console?

Comment: **Always** check for and include any errors when asking a question.

Comment: You're code also doesn't have commas after each `"jan16": 0`. Is this the exact code you're using? After fixing that syntax error, the code you posted works just fine, e.g., updates the `data` object.

Comment: @qxz i updated op

Comment: That code still works for me. What is the context? How are you later using `data`?

Comment: I tried it in a loop and it's not updating the values

Comment: it works for me! maybe you can add this code to jsfiddle or somewhere with your real libraries then we can test and debug easier.

Comment: Life lesson: always include enough context such that the error can be reproduced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
let targetService = report[service][monthInterval];
```

Because the value of that property is a primitive number (i.e., not a reference type), `targetService` creates a clone of the value, not a reference to it. Therefore, incrementing `targetService` only changes `targetService`, not the original object.

Just replacing the problem line with `report[service][monthInterval] += cost;` should work. I don't think there is a more elegant way to do that.

Comment: makes sense, fixed the issue. Thanks.